# How to specify database on D9 installation

Tags: installation

This question was asked regarding wordpress but is also an issue for D9.  When installing from the extend page in Drupal, there is no option to specify the schema for Civi, so all the tables end up mixed with Drupal.  The solution of manually moving the tables and editing civicrm_settings.php seems hackish.

Did I just miss the configuration step for this?

Comment: Is using `cv` an option for you? It's more flexible. See https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/general/cli-cv/

Answer (score 1):

If you start by configuring the separate database in civicrm_settings.php before enabling the module, the database tables will be created in the seperate database.

If you already have half installed CiviCRM, like me, with the drupal module installed but not the database then cv is your answer. CV allows you to specify the database connection string

```
cv core:install --cms-base-url=https://www.doinggood.org/ --db mysql://doinggood_crm:pass@localhost/doinggood_user
```

Comment: I tried configuring civicrm_settings.php but the changes were overwritten when the D9 install ran.

hmm.